# Newsletter works with mysql_connect but not with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to script a Newsletter.
With mysql_connect the newsletter does work; Email received and my echo string with listed emails also work.
If I want to translate it to PDO, any email is sent and no string to see, also i do not get any error message. (German strings in script)

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'name', 'pw')
or die ("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");
mysql_select_db('***')
or die ("Datenbank nicht gefunden");
$betreff = 'Newsletter';
$nachricht = 'Sehr geehrte/geehrter ##anrede## ##vorname## ##nachname##,' . "\n\n" .
              'der neue Newsletter ist da.';
$header = 'FROM: newsletter@test.abc' . "\r\n" .
          'Replay-To: anfrage@test.abc';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM newsletter";
$erg = mysql_query($sql);

$sqlemail = "SELECT email FROM newsletter";

$result = mysql_query($sqlemail);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  $email = $row->email;
    foreach ($row as $email) {
      mail($email, $betreff, $nachricht, $header);
      echo "Email versendet an $email <br  />";
    }
}
?>


<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', 'name', 'pw');

$betreff = 'Newsletter';
$nachricht = 'Sehr geehrte/geehrter ##anrede## ##vorname## ##nachname##,' . "\n\n" .
              'der neue Newsletter ist da.';
$header = 'FROM: newsletter@test.abc' . "\r\n" .
          'Replay-To: anfrage@test.abc';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM newsletter";
$erg = mysql_query($sql);

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  $email = $row['email'];
  mail($email, $betreff, $nachricht, $header);
  echo "Email versendet an $email <br  />";
}

?>
```

Comment: and i got one page for mysql_connect and another for pdo

Comment: I suggest you read a PDO tutorial/example code, one obvious missing piece is that you need to actually fetch the results as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the pdo side,  you need to fetch the query as well.  Do this:

$pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll()

Comment: Should be in the foreach?
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
=>
foreach ($pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll() as $row) { 
?

Comment: Yes.  Replace it with what I gave you

Comment: Well, still no newsletter mails from pdo :(

Comment: Do a print of the array.  What do you get

Comment: Nothing... ok i will script it new from beginning, any print or echo does work, maybe i will find my mistake but Thank you for your time

Comment: A `PDOStatement`, which `query` returns, is iterable by itself. You *don't* need `fetchAll`.